# The deployed app through Heroku doesn't show visitor's ip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I deployed my app using heroku service. On my local mashine it shows clearly `127.0.0.1 Reserved` when i type

```
<%= request.ip %>   
<%= request.location.city %>    
<%= request.location.country %>
```

but when i deploy it through Heroku i don't get any ip, where is the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

try remote_ip instead

```
request.remote_ip
```

Comment: 2016-02-07T15:26:45.131907+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=handkock.herokuapp.com request_id=1e8587aa-f629-49fa-945d-4f92e4e4a2e9 fwd="83.219.151.186" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Comment: Seems like a larger problem. Changing ip to remote_ip alone would not cause your app to crash so long as it wasn't crashing with the ip method already